# Keras concatenate Sequential and Dense models

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, concatenation, lstm

I have the following models:

**Dense Model:**

```
def dense_model(num_features):
  inputs = Input(shape=(num_features,), dtype=tf.float32)
  layers = Dense(32, activation='relu')(inputs)
  model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=layers)
  
  return model
```

[image]

**LSTM Model:**

```
def lstm_model(num_features):

    inputs = Input(shape=[None, num_features], dtype=tf.float32, ragged=True)
    layers = LSTM(16, activation='tanh')(
        inputs.to_tensor(), mask=tf.sequence_mask(inputs.row_lengths()))

    layers = BatchNormalization()(layers)
    layers = Dense(16,activation='relu')(layers)
    layers = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(layers)
    
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=layers)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
        
    return model
```

[image]

---

I'm trying to concatenate the two networks like so:

```
def concatenate_model(num_features):
    model_1 = dense_model(10)
    inputs = Input(shape=[None, num_features], dtype=tf.float32, ragged=True)
    layers = LSTM(16, activation='tanh')(
        inputs.to_tensor(), mask=tf.sequence_mask(inputs.row_lengths()))

    layers = BatchNormalization()(layers)
    layers = Dense(16,activation='relu')(concatenate([layers,model_1]))
    layers = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(layers)
    
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=layers)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
        
    return model
```

to get the following result:
[image]

But I get an error:

```
ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.
```

[**Here is a Colab**](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bSd8vbZ6HDIwDt03LpjwChRO08h2hD5C?usp=sharing) that demonstrate my issue. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def dense_model(num_features):
  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(num_features,), dtype=tf.float32)
  layers = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(inputs)
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=layers)
  
  return model

def lstm_model(num_features):

    model_1 = dense_model(10)
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None, num_features], dtype=tf.float32, ragged=True)
    layers = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16, activation='tanh')(
        inputs.to_tensor(), mask=tf.sequence_mask(inputs.row_lengths()))

    layers = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(layers)
    concatenated = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([layers, model_1.output])
    layers = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16,activation='relu')(concatenated)
    layers = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(layers)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs, model_1.input], outputs=layers)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
        
    return model

model = lstm_model(20)
dot_img_file = '/model.png'
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file=dot_img_file, show_shapes=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, can you elaborate what I've done wrong?

Comment: You just need to explicitly tell your `LSTM` model that it should use the input of the `dense_model` as one of its inputs and the output should be `model.output` and not simply `model` as you need the output of the last layer and not the model object itself. You could also use `model_1.layers[-1].output]`, would have the same effect.